Langchain get_openai_callback doesn't track the token usage for AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
I have a RAG application built on langchain. I am tracking the tokens and cost usage for my application in the database, I can track the usage of the token for AzureOpenAI using get_openai_callback however it is not tracking the token usage for Embeddings (I am using FAISS as embedding DB).
AzureOpenAIEmbeddings returns token usage:
{
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
        {
            "object": "embedding",
            "index": 0,
            "embedding": [...]
        }
    ],
    "model": "text-embedding-ada-002",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 823,
        "total_tokens": 823
    }
}

However get_openai_callback is not tracking it:
Tokens Used: 0
Prompt Tokens: 0
Completion Tokens: 0
Successful Requests: 0
Total Cost (USD): $0.0

Following is the code block where I am creating the FAISS DB and I want to track the token usage.
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
import constants

def getEmbeddings(docs, text_splitter):

    embedding_model = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
        azure_deployment=constants.AZURE_OPEN_AI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        openai_api_version=constants.AZURE_OPEN_AI_API_VERSION,
    )

    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)

    db = FAISS.from_documents(texts, embedding_model)
    
    return db

